# Telethon telegram, distinguish from channel messages and private messages

Tags: bots, telegram, message, telethon

I have to send few private commands to bot. How do you know if the event message is private or from channel/group ?

I found this in the obj message:

```
PeerUser(user_id=xxxxxxxxx) - private message from User
from_id=None  <-- none

PeerChannel(channel_id=hhhhhhhhhh)  - message from channel
from_id=PeerUser(user_id=xxxxxxxxxx) - from_id got the user_id
```

How to test it ?Do I have to look for attribute PeerUser or PeerChannel ?
or Do I have to test 'from_id' ?:

```
if not from_id :
  # private message
 else:
  # channel message
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telethon has events.

If you debug the input of an event you see multiple parameters.
event.is_private

Is a parameter which is either true or false.
Example code:

```
​from​ ​telethon​ ​import​ ​events
 
​async​ ​def​ ​init​(​bot​, ​session​): 
​    ​@​bot​.​on​(​events​.​NewMessage​(​incoming​=​True​, ​pattern​=​r"/test"​)) 
​    ​async​ ​def​ ​handler​(​event​): 
​        ​if​ ​event​.​is_private​:
```

It's a working snippet from one of my codes. Try the debigger to see what an event does contain else. It holds a lot of usefull data.

Comment: Found . thanks https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/objects-reference.html?highlight=is_private#chatgetter